# JVM - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION seen in the logs

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

I am getting EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when I am trying to send an image file to the service through my SOAP UI.
This issue seems to be related to the JVM. I have tried setting some parameters like -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false but still the problem persists. I've tried increasing the heap size too. Any help is appreciated.

```
  


    #
        # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
        #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x023c172c, pid=5468, tid=20200
        #
        # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
        # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
        # Problematic frame:
        # C  [fontmanager.dll+0x172c]
        #
        # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
        #
        # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
        # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
        ----------  T H R E A D  --------
        Current thread (0x05c7a800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=20200, stack(0x055f0000,0x05640000)]

        siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000000

        Registers:
        EAX=0x063e96a0, EBX=0x01dd2fac, ECX=0x00000008, EDX=0x00000008
        ESP=0x0563e07c, EBP=0x0563e0e0, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x05c7a930
        EIP=0x023c172c, EFLAGS=0x00010212

        Top of Stack: (sp=0x0563e07c)
        0x0563e07c:   00000000 05c7a930 51043170 51043170
        0x0563e08c:   3a418ab8 00043170 42d40000 437c0000
        0x0563e09c:   0563e154 01dd2fac 74160691 00000000
        0x0563e0ac:   063e96a0 51043170 0563e0a4 0563e0f0
        0x0563e0bc:   0563ed40 6e6d068e 1f01cd95 fffffffe
        0x0563e0cc:   0563e138 6c08147d 05c7a930 0563e154
        0x0563e0dc:   00000022 6c176b28 023c1f27 05c7a930
        0x0563e0ec:   0563e148 51043170 05c7a800 0563e138 

        Instructions: (pc=0x023c172c)
        0x023c170c:   44 24 13 8b c3 c1 e0 05 83 c0 08 50 ff 15 c0 e0
        0x023c171c:   3d 02 8b f0 8b 44 24 30 83 c4 04 8d 4e 08 6a 00
        0x023c172c:   89 1e 89 4e 04 8b 17 8b 8a 78 03 00 00 50 57 ff
        0x023c173c:   d1 8b d8 89 5c 24 24 85 db 74 6e 80 7c 24 13 00 

        Register to memory mapping:

        EAX=0x063e96a0 is an unknown value
        EBX=0x01dd2fac is an unknown value
        ECX=0x00000008 is an unknown value
        EDX=0x00000008 is an unknown value
        ESP=0x0563e07c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05c7a800
        EBP=0x0563e0e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x05c7a800
        ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
        EDI=0x05c7a930 is an unknown value

        Stack: [0x055f0000,0x05640000],  sp=0x0563e07c,  free space=312k
        Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
        C  [fontmanager.dll+0x172c]

        Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
        j  sun.java2d.loops.DrawGlyphListLCD.DrawGlyphListLCD(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;Lsun/font/GlyphList;)V+0
        j  sun.java2d.pipe.LCDTextRenderer.drawGlyphList(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;Lsun/font/GlyphList;)V+13
        j  sun.java2d.pipe.GlyphListPipe.drawChars(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;[CIIII)V+167
        j  sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawChars([CIIII)V+106
        J  org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.DefaultTokenPainter.paintImpl(Lorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/Token;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;FFLorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/RSyntaxTextArea;Ljavax/swing/text/TabExpander;FZ)F
        j  org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.DefaultTokenPainter.paint(Lorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/Token;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;FFLorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/RSyntaxTextArea;Ljavax/swing/text/TabExpander;F)F+13
        j  org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.SyntaxView.drawLine(Lorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/TokenPainter;Lorg/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/Token;Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;FF)F+45
        j  org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.SyntaxView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljava/awt/Shape;)V+368
        j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljava/awt/Shape;)V+48
        j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+65
        j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+45
        j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(Ljava/awt/Graphics;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)V+3
        j  org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+31
        j  org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.paintComponent(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+6
        j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+286
        J  javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V
        j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+318
        j  javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+205
        J  javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V
        j  javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+318
        j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIIIII)V+41
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Image;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V+163
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)Z+116
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Graphics;IIII)V+52
        j  javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(IIII)V+683
        j  javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(IIII)V+138
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+75
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
        v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
        J  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        J  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Ljava/util/Map;)V+154
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions()V+46
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions()V+73
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Ljavax/swing/RepaintManager;)V+1
        j  javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run()V+37
        j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
        j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
        j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
        j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
        j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
        v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
        J  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        J  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
        J  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V
        j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
        j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
        j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
        j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
        j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
        v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

        ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

        Java Threads: ( => current thread )
          0x05d1bc00 JavaThread "Prism Font Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22352, stack(0x0b510000,0x0b560000)]
          0x05d1b000 JavaThread "Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14820, stack(0x07270000,0x072c0000)]
          0x05d1a800 JavaThread "Thread-14" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=17600, stack(0x0b450000,0x0b4a0000)]
          0x05d1a400 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=8560, stack(0x09ef0000,0x09f40000)]
          0x05d19c00 JavaThread "Thread-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17548, stack(0x076f0000,0x07740000)]
          0x05d19800 JavaThread "Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20688, stack(0x09dc0000,0x09e10000)]
          0x05d19000 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13124, stack(0x073d0000,0x07420000)]
          0x05d18c00 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19144, stack(0x08560000,0x085b0000)]
          0x05d18400 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=21512, stack(0x02330000,0x02380000)]
          0x05d17c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1198" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=21664, stack(0x02280000,0x022d0000)]
          0x05d17000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22192, stack(0x05ea0000,0x05ef0000)]
          0x06aa3800 JavaThread "MemoryMonitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1848, stack(0x06fe0000,0x07030000)]
          0x06a50800 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=12308, stack(0x077c0000,0x07810000)]
          0x06920800 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=8912, stack(0x07760000,0x077b0000)]
          0x0694fc00 JavaThread "Thread-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15864, stack(0x07190000,0x071e0000)]
          0x064df000 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=10532, stack(0x06de0000,0x06e30000)]
          0x05dcf800 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21740, stack(0x056c0000,0x05710000)]
          0x0217fc00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=19660, stack(0x02450000,0x024a0000)]
        =>0x05c7a800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=20200, stack(0x055f0000,0x05640000)]
          0x05c7a000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=20040, stack(0x06330000,0x06380000)]
          0x05c75800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=11424, stack(0x06190000,0x061e0000)]
          0x05c37000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21452, stack(0x05fc0000,0x06010000)]
          0x05c2d400 JavaThread "Timer-0" [_thread_blocked, id=9580, stack(0x05f30000,0x05f80000)]
          0x04c27800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18104, stack(0x05970000,0x059c0000)]
          0x04c22000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17420, stack(0x05850000,0x058a0000)]
          0x04c20c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15156, stack(0x05710000,0x05760000)]
          0x04bf1400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15160, stack(0x057f0000,0x05840000)]
          0x04bed000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21408, stack(0x02180000,0x021d0000)]
          0x04be8000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21540, stack(0x05210000,0x05260000)]

        Other Threads:
          0x04be5c00 VMThread [stack: 0x04f40000,0x04f90000] [id=7208]
          0x04c41400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x05a00000,0x05a50000] [id=15244]

        VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

        VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

        Heap
         def new generation   total 256832K, used 510K [0x10080000, 0x21720000, 0x255d0000)
          eden space 228352K,   0% used [0x10080000, 0x100ff8a8, 0x1df80000)
          from space 28480K,   0% used [0x1df80000, 0x1df80000, 0x1fb50000)
          to   space 28480K,   0% used [0x1fb50000, 0x1fb50000, 0x21720000)
         tenured generation   total 699072K, used 586626K [0x255d0000, 0x50080000, 0x50080000)
           the space 699072K,  83% used [0x255d0000, 0x492b0828, 0x492b0a00, 0x50080000)
         compacting perm gen  total 28672K, used 28503K [0x50080000, 0x51c80000, 0x54080000)
           the space 28672K,  99% used [0x50080000, 0x51c55d68, 0x51c55e00, 0x51c80000)
        No shared spaces configured.

        Card table byte_map: [0x04840000,0x04a70000] byte_map_base: 0x047bfc00

        Polling page: 0x001f0000

        Code Cache  [0x02840000, 0x02bc8000, 0x04840000)
         total_blobs=2197 nmethods=1804 adapters=327 free_code_cache=29170Kb largest_free_block=29868416

        Compilation events (10 events):
        Event: 93.820 Thread 0x04c22000 1836             com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout::sum (25 bytes)
        Event: 93.821 Thread 0x04c22000 nmethod 1836 0x02bbf988 code [0x02bbfa80, 0x02bbfb40]
        Event: 94.040 Thread 0x04c22000 1837 %           org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.DefaultTokenPainter::paintImpl @ 107 (421 bytes)
        Event: 94.043 Thread 0x04c22000 nmethod 1837% 0x02bbfc08 code [0x02bbfed0, 0x02bc0c0c]
        Event: 94.805 Thread 0x04c22000 1838             sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper::getCachedGlyphCode (32 bytes)
        Event: 94.805 Thread 0x04c22000 nmethod 1838 0x02bc1c88 code [0x02bc1d90, 0x02bc1e90]
        Event: 94.805 Thread 0x04c22000 1839 %           sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper::charsToGlyphsNS @ 3 (158 bytes)
        Event: 94.806 Thread 0x04c22000 nmethod 1839% 0x02bc1fc8 code [0x02bc2100, 0x02bc2438]
        Event: 95.001 Thread 0x04c22000 1840 %           sun.font.FileFontStrike::getSlot0GlyphImagePtrs @ 6 (128 bytes)
        Event: 95.002 Thread 0x04c22000 nmethod 1840% 0x02bc28c8 code [0x02bc2aa0, 0x02bc33d4]

        GC Heap History (10 events):
        Event: 92.251 GC heap before
        {Heap before GC invocations=22 (full 7):
         def new generation   total 121088K, used 62203K [0x10080000, 0x183e0000, 0x255d0000)
          eden space 107648K,  57% used [0x10080000, 0x13d3edf8, 0x169a0000)
          from space 13440K,   0% used [0x169a0000, 0x169a0000, 0x176c0000)
          to   space 13440K,   0% used [0x176c0000, 0x176c0000, 0x183e0000)
         tenured generation   total 268948K, used 161368K [0x255d0000, 0x35c75000, 0x50080000)
           the space 268948K,  59% used [0x255d0000, 0x2f366168, 0x2f366200, 0x35c75000)
         compacting perm gen  total 28672K, used 28444K [0x50080000, 0x51c80000, 0x54080000)
           the space 28672K,  99% used [0x50080000, 0x51c472c8, 0x51c47400, 0x51c80000)
        No shared spaces configured.
        Event: 92.270 GC heap after
        Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 7):
         def new generation   total 121088K, used 0K [0x10080000, 0x183e0000, 0x255d0000)
          eden space 107648K,   0% used [0x10080000, 0x10080000, 0x169a0000)
          from space 13440K,   0% used [0x176c0000, 0x176c0040, 0x183e0000)
          to   space 13440K,   0% used [0x169a0000, 0x169a0000, 0x176c0000)
         tenured generation   total 268948K, used 222450K [0x255d0000, 0x35c75000, 0x50080000)
           the space 268948K,  82% used [0x255d0000, 0x32f0cae0, 0x32f0cc00, 0x35c75000)
         compacting perm gen  total 28672K, used 28444K [0x50080000, 0x51c80000, 0x54080000)
           the space 28672K,  99% used [0x50080000, 0x51c472c8, 0x51c47400, 0x51c80000)
        No shared spaces configured.
        }
        Event: 92.299 GC heap before
        {Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 7):
         def new generation   total 121088K, used 62397K [0x10080000, 0x183e0000, 0x255d0000)
          eden space 107648K,  57% used [0x10080000, 0x13d6f570, 0x169a0000)
          from space 13440K,   0% used [0x176c0000, 0x176c0040, 0x183e0000)
          to   space 13440K,   0% used [0x169a0000, 0x169a0000, 0x176c0000)
         tenured generation   total 268948K, used 222450K [0x255d0000, 0x35c75000, 0x50080000)
           the space 268948K,  82% used [0x255d0000, 0x32f0cae0, 0x32f0cc00, 0x35c75000)
         compacting perm gen  total 28672K, used 28444K [0x50080000, 0x51c80000, 0x54080000)
           the space 28672K,  99% used [0x50080000, 0x51c472c8, 0x51c47400, 0x51c80000)
        No shared spaces configured.
        Event: 92.503 GC heap after
        Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 8):
         def new generation   total 165248K, used 0K [0x10080000, 0x1b3c0000, 0x255d0000)
          eden space 146944K,   0% used [0x10080000, 0x10080000, 0x19000000)
          from space 18304K,   0% used [0x19000000, 0x19000000, 0x1a1e0000)
          to   space 18304K,   0% used [0x1a1e0000, 0x1a1e0000, 0x1b3c0000)
         tenured generation   total 366964K, used 220177K [0x255d0000, 0x3bc2d000, 0x50080000)
           the space 366964K,  59% used [0x255d0000, 0x32cd47d8, 0x32cd4800, 0x3bc2d000)
         compacting perm gen  total 28672K, used 28436K [0x50080000, 0x51c80000, 0x54080000)
           the space 28672K,  99% used [0x50080000, 0x51c45210, 0x51c45400, 0x51c80000)

        Deoptimization events (0 events):
        No events

        Internal exceptions (10 events):
        Event: 83.320 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x1010ef08 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.367 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x13c2bd98 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.367 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x13c43810 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.369 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x13c59de8 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.370 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x13c66cc8 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.370 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x17852aa0 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.371 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x1785e6e0 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.371 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x17868d50 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.371 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x17874ef0 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
        Event: 93.376 Thread 0x05c7a800 Threw 0x17882ac0 at C:\re\jdk7u55\869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

        Events (10 events):
        Event: 93.371 loading class 0x0cfa2ff8
        Event: 93.371 loading class 0x0cfa2ff8 done
        Event: 93.376 loading class 0x0d089288
        Event: 93.376 loading class 0x0d089288 done
        Event: 94.254 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
        Event: 94.278 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
        Event: 94.294 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
        Event: 94.547 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
        Event: 94.555 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
        Event: 94.661 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done


        Dynamic libraries:
        0x00b60000 - 0x00b8f000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\java.exe
        0x77c10000 - 0x77d90000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
        0x758a0000 - 0x759b0000     C:\windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
        0x772e0000 - 0x77327000     C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
        0x752b0000 - 0x7532f000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\SYSFER.DLL
        0x76500000 - 0x765a1000     C:\windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
        0x75e00000 - 0x75eac000     C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
        0x75780000 - 0x75799000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
        0x77360000 - 0x77450000     C:\windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
        0x754c0000 - 0x75520000     C:\windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
        0x754b0000 - 0x754bc000     C:\windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
        0x76050000 - 0x76150000     C:\windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
        0x777a0000 - 0x77830000     C:\windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
        0x77700000 - 0x7770a000     C:\windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
        0x76220000 - 0x762bd000     C:\windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
        0x71840000 - 0x719de000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.23403_none_2b180b30457f196c\COMCTL32.dll
        0x75570000 - 0x755c7000     C:\windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
        0x75720000 - 0x75780000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
        0x76150000 - 0x7621d000     C:\windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
        0x746e0000 - 0x746ef000     C:\windows\system32\PGPmapih.dll
        0x01f90000 - 0x0204f000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
        0x6e440000 - 0x6e7c0000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
        0x72e60000 - 0x72e67000     C:\windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
        0x75dc0000 - 0x75df5000     C:\windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
        0x75eb0000 - 0x75eb6000     C:\windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
        0x6da40000 - 0x6da72000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
        0x76000000 - 0x76005000     C:\windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
        0x54950000 - 0x54985000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\splashscreen.dll
        0x70cf0000 - 0x70d70000     C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
        0x6f7c0000 - 0x6f7cc000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\verify.dll
        0x63ed0000 - 0x63ef0000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\java.dll
        0x69f40000 - 0x69f4e000     C:\windows\system32\PGPhk.dll
        0x10000000 - 0x10072000     C:\Program Files (x86)\PolicyPak\Application Manager\Client\17.12.1560\PPAppLockLdr32.dll
        0x765b0000 - 0x771fc000     C:\windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
        0x73aa0000 - 0x73aa3000     C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL
        0x63fb0000 - 0x63fc3000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\zip.dll
        0x75c60000 - 0x75dbd000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
        0x63eb0000 - 0x63ec4000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\net.dll
        0x74590000 - 0x745cc000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
        0x74280000 - 0x74286000     C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll
        0x69020000 - 0x6902f000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\nio.dll
        0x6c080000 - 0x6c1c3000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\awt.dll
        0x75a20000 - 0x75ab1000     C:\windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
        0x6afa0000 - 0x6afb3000     C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
        0x6f8e0000 - 0x6f8ea000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\management.dll
        0x63e90000 - 0x63eb0000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\sunec.dll
        0x63fa0000 - 0x63fa9000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
        0x75ed0000 - 0x75ff1000     C:\windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
        0x75ec0000 - 0x75ecc000     C:\windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
        0x74560000 - 0x74577000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
        0x74520000 - 0x7455b000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
        0x757d0000 - 0x757e9000     C:\windows\syswow64\USERENV.dll
        0x757c0000 - 0x757cb000     C:\windows\syswow64\profapi.dll
        0x74360000 - 0x7437c000     C:\windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
        0x74350000 - 0x74357000     C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
        0x74380000 - 0x74392000     C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
        0x74340000 - 0x7434d000     C:\windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
        0x67d80000 - 0x67d90000     C:\windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
        0x67d70000 - 0x67d80000     C:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll
        0x67d50000 - 0x67d62000     C:\windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
        0x67d40000 - 0x67d4d000     C:\windows\system32\wshbth.dll
        0x717f0000 - 0x71834000     C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
        0x67d30000 - 0x67d38000     C:\windows\System32\winrnr.dll
        0x74580000 - 0x74585000     C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
        0x6d5a0000 - 0x6d5a6000     C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
        0x74240000 - 0x74278000     C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
        0x023c0000 - 0x023f9000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
        0x54e80000 - 0x54eb0000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\t2k.dll
        0x77710000 - 0x77793000     C:\windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
        0x68ee0000 - 0x69011000     C:\windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
        0x6c630000 - 0x6c67c000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
        0x0f2a0000 - 0x0f424000     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6301.0127\FileSyncShell.dll
        0x0fef0000 - 0x0ff61000     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6301.0127\MSVCP120.dll
        0x0f510000 - 0x0f5fe000     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6301.0127\MSVCR120.dll
        0x0fa00000 - 0x0fa4d000     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6301.0127\Telemetry.dll
        0x0fb40000 - 0x0fb5c000     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\17.3.6301.0127\LoggingPlatform.DLL
        0x74780000 - 0x74789000     C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll
        0x6bab0000 - 0x6bac5000     C:\windows\system32\Cabinet.dll
        0x72b50000 - 0x72ba8000     C:\windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
        0x72b00000 - 0x72b50000     C:\windows\system32\webio.dll
        0x77450000 - 0x776fb000     C:\windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
        0x77290000 - 0x77294000     C:\windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
        0x757a0000 - 0x757a4000     C:\windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
        0x76040000 - 0x76044000     C:\windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
        0x757b0000 - 0x757b3000     C:\windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
        0x77350000 - 0x77353000     C:\windows\syswow64\normaliz.DLL
        0x762c0000 - 0x764f6000     C:\windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
        0x759b0000 - 0x759b5000     C:\windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
        0x0fd50000 - 0x0fe78000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\PGPfsshl.dll
        0x73fc0000 - 0x73fd2000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\MPR.dll
        0x73fa0000 - 0x73fb1000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\NETAPI32.dll
        0x73f90000 - 0x73f99000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\netutils.dll
        0x73f70000 - 0x73f89000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\srvcli.dll
        0x73f60000 - 0x73f6f000     C:\windows\SysWOW64\wkscli.dll
        0x69f50000 - 0x69f5d000     C:\windows\system32\DFSCLI.DLL
        0x0b6b0000 - 0x0b6e1000     C:\windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
        0x75ac0000 - 0x75c5d000     C:\windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
        0x772b0000 - 0x772d7000     C:\windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
        0x77330000 - 0x77342000     C:\windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
        0x73b80000 - 0x73c75000     C:\windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
        0x69030000 - 0x690a0000     C:\windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
        0x6fcf0000 - 0x6fcfb000     C:\windows\system32\cscapi.dll
        0x741a0000 - 0x741aa000     C:\windows\system32\slc.dll
        0x63f70000 - 0x63f7d000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\prism-d3d.dll
        0x07420000 - 0x075e3000     C:\windows\system32\d3d9.dll
        0x00810000 - 0x00816000     C:\windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
        0x086f0000 - 0x09d56000     C:\windows\system32\igdumdim32.dll
        0x54bc0000 - 0x54be7000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\glass.dll
        0x757f0000 - 0x7586b000     C:\windows\syswow64\COMDLG32.dll
        0x5e960000 - 0x5f1cd000     C:\windows\system32\igdusc32.dll
        0x6d400000 - 0x6d47c000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\libxml2.dll
        0x54460000 - 0x5448a000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\libxslt.dll
        0x0b6f0000 - 0x0c250000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\jfxwebkit.dll
        0x54420000 - 0x5445d000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\javafx-font.dll
        0x77da0000 - 0x77dc4000     C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\jre\bin\dcpr.dll
        0x745f0000 - 0x746db000     C:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

        VM Arguments:
        jvm_args: -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties -Dsoapui.home=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\ -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsoapui.ext.libraries=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\ext -Dsoapui.ext.listeners=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\listeners -Dsoapui.ext.actions=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\actions -Djava.library.path=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\ -Dwsi.dir=C:\SoapUI-5.1.3\SoapUI-5.1.3\bin\..\wsi-test-tools 
        java_command: com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
        Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
```

Answer (score 1):

For my experience, this kind of error is usually due to a poor interaction with the JVM and the underlying window GFX driver.  I suggest updating your version of Java 7 to the latest (update 79) and ensure you have have the latest windows updates.

NOTE: This can happen if you run Java on a OS version which isn't supported.

If you can't update to Java 8, you might want to start planning to update to Java 11 which is the next Long Term Support release.